# How do I get this PHP code to output HTML?

Tags: php

How do I get this PHP code to output HTML in order to enter the player's number and generate the tournament?

```
<?php
class RoundRobin
{
 var $MaxTeams;
 var $MaxCombinations;
 var $tourn;
 var $mList;
 var $cList;
 var $cUsed;
 function RoundRobin($max)
 {
  $this->MaxTeams=$max;
  $this->MaxCombinations=($this->MaxTeams/2)*($this->MaxTeams-1);
 }
 function ShowSchedule($players,$totalChecks)
 {
   echo $players.' players'."\n";
   for ($r=1; $r <= $players/2; $r++) echo 'Game'.$r;
   echo "\n";
   echo"        +-";
   for ($r=1; $r <= ($players/2)*6-2; $r++) echo '-';
   echo "\n";
   $index = 1;
   for ($r=1; $r <= $players-1; $r++)
   {
     echo 'Week '.$r. '|';
     for ($m=1; $m <= $players/2; $m++)
     {
       echo $this->tourn[$index]['one'].'&amp;'. $this->tourn[$index]['two'];
       $index++;
     }
     echo "\n";
   }
   echo "\n".$totalChecks,' combinations tried'. "\n\n";
 }
 function array_copy(&$dest,$source)
 {
  if(count($source)>count($dest)) {echo 'fatal'; exit;}
  //for($a=0;$a<count($source);$a++)
  $dest['one']=$source['one'];
  $dest['two']=$source['two'];
 }
 function ClearArrays()
 {
   for ($i=0; $i <= $this->MaxCombinations; $i++)
   {
    $this->tourn[$i]['one']=0;
    $this->tourn[$i]['two']=0;
    $this->cList[$i]['one']=0;
    $this->cList[$i]['two']=0;
    $this->cUsed[$i]=0;
    if($i<=$this->MaxTeams/2)$this->mList[$i] = 0;
   }
 }
 function Scheldule($players)
 {
  while ($players <= $this->MaxTeams)
  {
 $combinations = $players/2 * ($players-1);
    $totalChecks = 0;
 $this->ClearArrays();
    /* set up list of all combinations */
     $m=1;
     for ($a=1; $a<$players; $a++)
      for ($b=$a+1; $b<=$players; $b++)
      {
       $this->cList[$m]['one'] = $a;
       $this->cList[$m]['two'] = $b;
       $m++;
      }
    $roundCount=1;
    $index=1;
    while ($roundCount <= $players-1)
     {
       $matchCount = 1;
       $round_set = 0;
       for ($i=0; $i<=$this->MaxTeams/2; $i++) $this->mList[$i] = 0;
       $startC = $roundCount;
         while ($matchCount <= $players/2)
         {
            $c = $combinations + 1;
            while ($c > $combinations)
            {
              $c = $startC;
              /* find an unused pair that would be legitimate */
              while (
                 ($c <= $combinations)
                 &&
                      ( //
                      ($round_set & (1 << $this->cList[$c]['one'])) ||
                       ($round_set & (1 << $this->cList[$c]['two'])) ||
                       (!empty($this->cUsed[$c]))
                      )
                    )   $c++;
                if ($c > $combinations)
                 {
                  do {
                    $this->mList[$matchCount] = 0;
                    $matchCount--;
                    $index--;
                    $round_set &= ~(1 << $this->cList[$this->mList[$matchCount]]['one']);
                    $round_set &= ~(1 << $this->cList[$this->mList[$matchCount]]['two']);
                    $this->cUsed[$this->mList[$matchCount]] = false;
                    $this->tourn[$index]['one'] = 0;
                    $this->tourn[$index]['two'] = 0;
                   }
                   while ($this->cList[$this->mList[$matchCount]]['one'] != $this->cList[$this->mList[$matchCount]+1]['one']);
                  $startC = $this->mList[$matchCount]+1;
                }
            }
            $this->array_copy(&$this->tourn[$index],$this->cList[$c]);
            $totalChecks++;
            if (($totalChecks % 1000) == 0) printf("%d\033A\n", $totalChecks );
            $this->cUsed[$c] = true;
            $this->mList[$matchCount] = $c;
            $startC = 1;
            $round_set |= (1 <<  $this->cList[$c]['one']);
            $round_set |= (1 <<  $this->cList[$c]['two']);
            $index++;
            $matchCount++;
         }
      $roundCount++;
     }
   /* yahoo!, scheduled all the rounds */
    printf("          " );
    $this->ShowSchedule($players,$totalChecks);
    /* try and make a schedule using two more teams */
   $players += 2;
   }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: So... what´s the question? How to write HTML to post to this script? I mean, you know how to code that intrincate script but don´t know how to write a simple HTML form?

Comment: Elaborate more the question and cut down the code you're pasting

Comment: I did'nt write it, I got it from my friend and I want to try to run it, but it did't work. Thats why I am asking.

Comment: No one is going to do this for you unless there's a 500 rep bounty

Comment: Hey Thomas ich brauche deine Hilfe, bitte!

Comment: Siva kauf dir ein Buch.. diese Plattform ist für Programmierer, die Ideen anregungen etc suchen die eventuell eine Funkktion suchen oder eine Klasse aber nicht die bitten, dass man ihnen ein ganzen Skript umbaut dazu gibt es Agenturen wir meine..

Answer (score 2):

It's a PHP class. Reading [the manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) might help you.

Something along the lines of this *might* work:

```
$rr = new RoundRobin( 5 );

$rr->Scheldule( $_POST['PlayerCount'] );
```

But I can't be bothered deciphering the code to work out if it really will.

Also, if you haven't yet learnt HTML forms, read a tutorial like [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/DEFAULT.asp).

Comment: Lol...I know how to do html...but it didnt work..thas y I asked